# Why does bash script add single quotes to string with asterisk?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a little script as a wrapper around this command:

```
$ egrep target /usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt 
/usr/lusers/me/test/1test.txt:target
```

That directory has files called `1test.txt` and `2test.txt`, one of which contains some text I want to find.
Here is my whole script, called `mygrep.sh`:

```
set -v
set -x
egrep "$1" '/usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt'
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ./mygrep.sh target
set -x
egrep "$1" '/usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt'
++ egrep targ '/usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt'
egrep: /usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Note the `'`s around the file path in the `set -x` output, and that the command fails.

Now compare this variation of the script:

```
set -v
set -x
egrep "$1" '/usr/lusers/me/test/1test.txt'
```

Note that the only difference is the asterisk vs the literal file name.
Output:

```
$ ./mygrep.sh target
set -x
egrep "$1" '/usr/lusers/me/test/1test.txt'
++ egrep target /usr/lusers/me/test/1test.txt
target
```

No single quotes after expansion, and the command works.

So why are those single quotes added when there's an asterisk, and why is the command failing in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output resulting from `set -x` is for debugging purposes. No quotes are added to the argument; they are just for display purposes.

The correct command is `egrep "$1" /usr/lusers/me/test/*.test.txt`, because the shell must expand the pattern (if possible) before passing the results to `egrep`. You don't have an actual file named `*.test.txt`.

Comment: I was thinking of passing the asterisk to egrep and letting it be expanded there. I suppose it doesn't matter, but is that possible?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Globbing (i.e. generating matching file names based on an expression) is a feature of the shell, not `egrep`.  If the asterisk makes it to `egrep`, it is a literal asterisk to that utility.

Comment: Actually, an asterisk can have a special meaning to `egrep` as part of a regular expression (not of a file name).  So please do not interpret my comment as meaning all asterisks are literal for `egrep`.

Answer (score 1):

The globbing character must be outside (single or double) quotes, as quotes disable globbing.

Use this instead :

```
egrep "$1" '/usr/lusers/me/test/'*'test.txt'
```

Or this :

```
egrep "$1" "/usr/lusers/me/test/"*"test.txt"
```

Or, since there is nothing inside this specific pattern that would cause word splitting to occur (but that would not be a generally safe way to do it if the path is not known safe in advance) :

```
egrep "$1" /usr/lusers/me/test/*test.txt
```